# React giving error on importing "entities" directory from the project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I use absolute imports in React application.

After creating "entities" directory on root of the React project and importing something from it, I have error:

```
Module not found: Error: Package path <package> is not exported from package node_modules/entities (see exports field in node_modules/entities/package.json)
```

The 'tsconfig.json' file config:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx"
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

The 'package.json' file config:

```
{
    "name": "allinbase-client",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^20.8.6",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.28",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.13",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.4.0",
        "eslint": "^8.0.1",
        "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^39.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
        "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 ",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
        "sass": "^1.69.3",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
        "typescript": "*"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

So, the example:

`entities/sidebar/ui/sidebar-container.tsx`

```
import { FC, ReactNode } from 'react'

export const SidebarContainer: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => (
    <div className="w-36 h-screen fixed border border-r border-black left-0 top-0">{children}</div>
)
```

`entities/sidebar/ui/index.tsx`

```
export * from './SidebarContainer'
```

`entities/sidebar/index.ts`

```
export * from './ui'
```

`widgets/sidebar.tsx`

```
import { SidebarContainer } from 'entities/sidebar'

export const Sidebar = () => (
    <SidebarContainer>
        <h2>Sidebar</h2>
    </SidebarContainer>
)
```

`app/index.tsx`

```
import { Sidebar } from 'widgets/sidebar/ui'
import './index.scss'

const App = () => (
    <>
        <Sidebar />
    </>
)

export default App
```

Tried to add 'paths' config to tsconfig.json file, not working:

```
...tsconfig configurations,
"paths": {
   "entities/*": ["entities/*"]
}
```